# Issue with uploading data into database

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am facing problem in sending data to database. The problem is every time i refresh the page it automatically send the previous data. Can any one help.

```
if (isset($_POST['Posts'])) {
    if (isset($_POST['t']) && isset($_POST['i']) && isset($_POST['P'])) {
        $title = $_POST['t'];
        $idea = $_POST['i'];

        if (!empty($title) && !empty($idea)) {
            $query = "INSERT INTO `updates` VALUES ('".mysql_real_escape_string($title)."')";
            if ($query_run = mysql_query($query)) { } 
            else {
                echo 'Sorry ,we could\'t register you at this time.Try again later';
            } 
        }                    
    }
}
```

Comment: That's because your browser sends the data again at each refresh, your browser should have prompted you that by the way

Comment: try wrap it with `if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST')`

Comment: it is so called 'RESEND'..to prevent it unset `$_POST` after inserting data into DB.

Comment: tried unset($_POST). not woring

Answer (score 1):

Clear your post data after insert in db.
Add below code after insertion db code.

```
$_POST = array();
```

like inside your if block

```
... 
 if ($query_run = mysql_query($query)) { $_POST = array(); } 
...
```

Comment: Hm... I am wondering. I am using this code to check your solution: `if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
 echo "Abc";
 unset($_POST);
}` But when I refresh, it always says `Abc`. Can you explain me, why it should work? Because browser is always resending the data.

Comment: I think while you refresh your page you choose resubmit page option

Comment: Yes, I am, this is why I do not understand this solution.

Comment: Oh, I see. It's clear the input values. Ok, I've just played with submit, not the values.

Comment: yes, right check ur text input val and add condition base on it like ur field is empty or not

Comment: hey, i have given the !empty condition. but still happening the same thing

Comment: you need to all your form filed to blank while page load from server for every time