# Issue with mysql data storage into database

Tags: php, mysql

After successfully sending data to my database upon reloading the page it resubmit automatically again. Does anyone know why?

After successfully submitting data the first time, it clears the values inside the text field, but if i reload the page it automatically sends the previously filled data again into database.

To avoid it i have tried !empty condition. I have also tried unset $_POST.
My code looks like this:

```
if (isset($_POST['Posts'])) {
    if (isset($_POST['t']) && isset($_POST['i']) && isset($_POST['P'])) {
        $title = $_POST['t'];
        $idea = $_POST['i'];

        if (!empty($title) && !empty($idea)) {
            $query = "INSERT INTO `updates` VALUES ('".mysql_real_escape_string($title)."')";
            if ($query_run = mysql_query($query)) { } 
            else {
                echo 'Sorry ,we could\'t register you at this time.Try again later';
            } 
        }                    
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a header to redirect instead of an echo or you can use cookies and/or sessions while using `isset()`.

Comment: You also posted this already http://stackoverflow.com/q/27702122/ and this question should be closed as an exact duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to add header at the end, example:

```
if (isset($_POST['Posts'])) { 
//do something

//..do all post stuff
header('Location: thisPage.php'); //clears POST
}
```

Comment: If OP has more code below what is presently posted, `exit;` should be added after header, otherwise the rest of the code will want to continue executing. Either way, it's always best adding `exit;` after header. http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Answer (score 0):

After running the insert, redirect to a new page. Or you could even run a select to check if the data was just submitted, though you might want to put a time frame such as has it been inserted in the past 5 minutes or so. If it has not been inserted, then do the insert.  If it was already inserted, either display the success message or a "this data has already been submitted" type answer.